# Print JavaScript variable in a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

Trying to print JS var `run_name` as a part of HTML content. Here is my small snippet out of my entire JS code:

```
var run_name = uiscripts.context.run.id; //uiscripts.context.run.id is a string
var markUp = "<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>Job is _____</h3>\r\n"; 
$("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);
```

`markUp` var holds the HTML content that I want to show as a part of `#startJobDialog`. You can see the blank underlined content in markUp var. I want to fill `run_name` var into that blank. That is Job is _____. How do I do it?

So far I have tried 2 approaches:

```
var markUp = "<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>Job is <var>run_name</var></h3>\r\n";
```

and this:

```
var run_name = uiscripts.context.run.id;
    var markUp = "<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>Job is _____</h3>\r\n";

    markUp += run_name;

    $("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You simply need to concatenate the value of `variable run_name` with `html`.

```
var markUp = "<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>Job is <span style='font-weight:bold'>"+run_name+"</span></h3>\r\n";
```

Comment: This solved my question, but flexibility in terms of color and font would be better for the var `run_name`. Is `<var color="something">` doable? I want to do something right in this line and may not be CSS. Suggestions.

Comment: I didn't get you ?

Comment: I am not sure, that you should use <var> tag at all.
To change the text colour you should use CSS.

Comment: Can I print var run_name in `bold or italic way`? I also want to `highlight the the value of var`, maybe by some color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var run_name = uiscripts.context.run.id; //uiscripts.context.run.id is a string
var markUp = "<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>Job is " + run_name + "</h3>\r\n"; 

$("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);
```

Also, In ES6 you can use interpolation within [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
If put string in `` and wrap variable into ${run_name}

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
var markUp = $('<h3>',{
class:'title',
style:'text-align: center',
text:"Job is "+run_name });
$("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);
```

Comment: `$('<h3>',{` quotes are missing and `;` should not have to be there after variable.

Comment: Not sure `$("#startJobDialog").append(markUp);` does not work but this: `$("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by defining `#startJobDialog` in a different way :-

```
<div id = "startJobDialog">
<h3 class='title' style='text-align: center'>
Job is <div id = "run_name"> </div>
</h3>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
$("#run_name").html(run_name);
```

Since your markup is not variable so you can put in in html itself.
Or you can just concatenate run_name in your markup variable using `+ markup +`